# Best way for verifying server compliance to Apple's ATS / TLS 1.2 requirement

Tags: ios, ssl, tls1.2, app-transport-security

So Apple requires TLS 1.2 with Forward Secrecy for URLs beginning iOS 9.  Independent of the app, what's the best way to verify that a server meets all the requirements?

nscurl just outright doesn't work - or I don't know how to use it.  My output simply repeatedly says CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed, even though I know the server is compliant.

TLSTool works to some extent but I cannot force the Forward Secrecy (FS) ciphers to be used.

openssl can specify specific cipher for the client mode, but the version I have doesn't have FS ciphers. How do I upgrade openssl?

What's the best way?  So far I've had to ssllabs.com's analyze.html.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Basically `nscurl --ats-diagnostics <url>` just tries all possible variants of connection to server and responses with PASS/FAIL results for each test. You should just find which tests pass for your server and set ATS configuration accordingly.

[Here's](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/app-transport-security.html) a good article on ATS and checking server compliance, it also contains an nscurl example.

Comment: Thanks! nscurl works for me now.  I can see it tries different combinations.

Answer (score 13):

All the methods listed here work, but require some manual labor. The best method I found was testing the server with SSL Labs and comparing the results to Apple's requirements. This seemed like something that could be automated so I created a tool that does just that: https://apptransport.info

If you pass your domain in as a parameter (e.g. https://apptransport.info/craigslist.com) you'll get the following information:

1. Whether or not your server is ATS compliant
2. How to fix your server if necessary
3. How to add ATS exceptions if necessary
4. The results From SSL Labs

Comment: Site is down: 
Application error - An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: I'll post an update here if it gets fixed or goes open source in its current state.

Answer (score 2):

Using `nscurl` (available in macOS El Capitan and higher), you can use the `--ats-tls-version` switch to test specifically for TLS 1.2 compliance, e.g.:

`nscurl --ats-diagnostics --ats-tls-version TLSv1.2 <url>`

This will also test for Perfect Forward Secrecy. If you want to disable testing for PFS, use the `--ats-disable-pfs` switch.

`nscurl --ats-diagnostics --ats-tls-version TLSv1.2 --ats-disable-pfs <url>`

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

If the URL you want to test is publicly accessible, you can use a public SSL testing service such as the one below:

[SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html)

After entering the URL, the section titled "Handshake Simulation" lists "Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9" and will indicate if TLS 1.2 was successfully negotiated and which connection cipher suite was used. If the cipher suite used is listed below under the Technical ATS Requirements and TLS 1.2 was successfully negotiated, then the server is properly configured for ATS.

**Method 2:** (this was mentioned by others as well)

On a Mac running OS X El Capitan, run the following command in Terminal:

```
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://<url>
```

After running the command, look for the section near the top labeled, `ATS Default Connection`. A result of `PASS` indicates the server is properly configured for ATS.

**Method 3:**

For URLs which are not publicly accessible, use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the communication to the URL. You can use a Wireshark filter to display only TLSv1.2 packets with the following:

```
ssl.record.version == 0x0303
```

You will see packets that use the TLSv1.2 protocol if the server has been configured for TLS version 1.2. If you only see a Client Hello packet when monitoring requests coming into the URL, then TLSv1.2 was not negotiated between the mobile device and the URL.

[image: wireshark_screenshot]