# Getting ATS failed system trust when connecting IOS app to asp.net API. Error Code 9813

Tags: ios, swift, api, ssl, certificate

I have an IOS app and a dot net API hosted on the same network. I've got a IP w.x.y.z I'm trying to allow through the info.plist because it doesn't have an SSL certificate. I understand that ip addresses are not supported so I'm using xip.io to convert it to a domain name.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>w.x.y.z.xip.io</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

My Swift Code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = URL(string: "https://w.x.y.z.xip.io:44328/api/values/1")!

        print("START")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
        print("DONE")

        task.resume()

    }
```

Going to https://w.x.y.z.xip.io:44328/api/values/1 works perfectly in my browser. When I try to run it I get

```
019-01-25 01:14:10.427331-0500 test_api[20555:3495649] ATS failed system trust
2019-01-25 01:14:10.427505-0500 test_api[20555:3495649] System Trust failed for [1:0x600000f8c900]
2019-01-25 01:14:10.427584-0500 test_api[20555:3495649] TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x600000f8c900]: 3:0
2019-01-25 01:14:10.432453-0500 test_api[20555:3495649] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2019-01-25 01:14:10.432601-0500 test_api[20555:3495649] Task <964CC4A4-C3C3-4349-80AA-E1DFC04920DA>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
2019-01-25 01:14:10.433065-0500 test_api[20555:3495648] Task <964CC4A4-C3C3-4349-80AA-E1DFC04920DA>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
```

Comment: Use `nscurl --ats-diagnostics <url>` - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444472/best-way-for-verifying-server-compliance-to-apples-ats-tls-1-2-requirement

Comment: So I used it but every single test failed. There were no passes.